# Convert Unix timestamp to two dataframe columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

The first column in the Pandas dataframe below is in Unix time format:

```
                Open      High       Low     Close
Timestamp                                         
1417411980    100.00    105.00     98.00     98.00
1417412040     98.00    105.00     96.00    105.00
1417412100    105.00    106.00    102.00    103.00
```

I want to convert it to two columns: date (say in format yyyymmdd), and time (hhmm). 
The resulting dataframe should then be saved to a CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.to_datetime` with `unit='s'`

```
ts = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='s')
print(
    df.assign(Date=ts.date, Time=ts.time).to_csv(index=False)
)

Open,High,Low,Close,Date,Time
100.0,105.0,98.0,98.0,2014-12-01,05:33:00
98.0,105.0,96.0,105.0,2014-12-01,05:34:00
105.0,106.0,102.0,103.0,2014-12-01,05:35:00
```